# In iOS, how do I make a popover close itself?

Tags: ios

I have a Settings popover. I have a button (More Info) in that popover. When the user clicks on that button, I want to bring up another view and I want to dismiss the popover.

How do I do this from my More Info button that is actually inside the popover?

Current I have a function that handles the button press:

```
 - (IBAction)showFullVersionInfo:(id)sender
   {
     [self dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
     parent.settingsPopover = nil;

     //need to show more Info...

   }
```

The parent holds a reference 'settingsPopover' to the popover and I want to clear it.

Comment: Looks like you have no trouble dismissing the popover, but you want to know how to show another view? Where/how do you want this view to be shown in relation to whatever UI is outside the popover?

Comment: @rickster The above code doesn't work to remove the popover...still trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to do this from inside the popover controller. The popover controller should manage only the contents of your popover, not how and when the popover is shown/hidden.

You can do such actions only in the parent controller. Hide the popover only from the controller which has shown it (and owns it).

Your question should actually be: how to tell the parent controller that the user has performed some action inside the popover?

And the answer is: delegate.
Define a delegate, implement it in your parent controller, pass it to your popover and in IBAction call delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to release popover in `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` delegate callback. Unfortunately this callback doesn't call after `dismissPopoverAnimated:`. I solved this by entering another unified callback named for example `popoverDidFinishWorking:`. Send it from popover to owner when close button was tapped, etc. When owner get `popoverDidFinishWorking:` it just invokes `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` and hides/release the popover (settingsPopover). You also can show any other view in this callback. Anyway it depends on your app design.

Comment: You should be careful with undefined stuff in iOS.  Apps get rejected on this basis.

Comment: So, I'm a lucky man. The App successfully placed on App5tore more than a year. Actually it is not "undefined stuff" but a part of good App design.

Answer (score 0):

In your 'parent' object in the function where you launch the settingsPopover you should have :

```
- (void) launchDismissSettingPopover {
    if (settingPopover == nil) {
         //Create an launch the popover
    } else {

        [self dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        // settingPopover will be nil in navigationController didShowViewController
         //self.settingsPopover = nil;
    }
}
```

You should have self.navigationController.delegate = self before in your parent class

```
-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
     if (viewController == self && self.settingPopover != nil) {

        //need to show more Info based on settingPopover info here

          self.settingPopover = nil ;
      }
}
```

Then in your popover class method

```
 - (IBAction)showFullVersionInfo:(id)sender
   {
     [parent launchDismissSettingPopover];
   }
```